# Click icon to trigger jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using the jquery timepicker (https://timepicker.co/) control. I am attempting to click on an icon to trigger the control which displays the selectable times in a dropdown. The code is as such:

```
$("#my-time-icon).click(function() {
    $("#my-time-ctl").focus();
});
```

This is exactly the way I do it for the jquery-ui datepicker and I have no problems. However, this control does not seem to work the same way. I can see that the dropdown flashes quickly, but the focus is never set. Curious if anyone has attempted to do a similar thing.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out:

```
$("#my-time-icon).click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#my-time-ctl").focus();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```